# Hudson project without user interface

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson

Can I configure, create/update the existing project in Hudson *without* using its user interface?
Is it possible by changing configuration file or other mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **[Remote Access API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API)** page mentions that you an create/copy job with it.

> Remote access API is offered in a REST-like style.
>   That is, there is no single entry point for all features, and instead they are available under the "**`.../api/`**" URL where "`...`" portion is the data that it acts on.
>
> For example, if your Hudson installation sits at `http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/`, `http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/api/` will give you HTML lists of all available functionality that act on the Hudson root.

On my Hudson, the /api address gives:

**Create Job**

> To create a new job, post **`config.xml`** to this URL with query parameter **`name=JOBNAME`**.
>   You'll get 200 status code if the creation is successful, or 4xx/5xx code if it fails.
>   `config.xml` is the format Hudson uses to store the project in the file system, so you can see examples of them in `/server/path/to/your/hudson/home`.